# Swift: Setting variable value inside UIAlertAction

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am declaring a variable, then trying to set its value inside UIAlertAction. When I tap the **"I am going there"** button In my below code the output is:

> 1 thisCustomerRequesting: true
>
> 3 thisCustomerRequesting: false

Can you tell my why line **"2 thisCustomerRequesting: ...."** is missing from output and why **"3 thisCustomerRequesting: false"** is false while i expect it to be true.

```
var thisCustomerRequesting = false
if thisCustomerRequesting == false {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "I am going there", style: .destructive, handler: {
        (alertAction1: UIAlertAction) in
            thisCustomerRequesting = true
            print("1 thisCustomerRequesting: \(thisCustomerRequesting)")
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default,handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("2 thisCustomerRequesting: \(thisCustomerRequesting)")
}               
print("3 thisCustomerRequesting: \(thisCustomerRequesting)")
```

Comment: I'm seeing the order of 2-3-1 on my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output 2 should be in your console but above `1 thisCustomerRequesting: true`.

Output 3 says `3 thisCustomerRequesting: false` because `thisCustomerRequesting` gets set to `true` asynchronously when the user presses the button.
At that time `print("3 thisCustomerRequesting: \(thisCustomerRequesting)")` is already executed.

Comment: is there any way around it. An obvious one is to use alert's completion handler but I have code below and including `print("3 thisCustomerRequesting:...` which should get executed even when if statement block is not executed.

Comment: @Kashif Encapsulate that code in a function an call it from both places.